# What is $b$ in this "conic general form" equation of a circle? $x^2+y^2+4x-4y-17=0$

Tags: circles, conic-sections

Take the equation of a circle from this [khanacademy video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/intro-to-conics-alg2/expanded-equation-circle-alg2/v/completing-the-square-to-write-equation-in-standard-form-of-a-circle) as an example:

$$x^2+y^2+4x-4y-17=0$$

$$a=x^2$$
$$b= ? $$
$$c=y^2$$
$$d=4x$$
$$e=-4y$$
$$f=-17$$

What is b equal to, and why did we "jump" over that?

Comment: $b=0$ <some extra characters>

Comment: I would guess that somewhere earlier in that lesson or in a previous one, they introduced the general _conic_ equation. I’d suggest that you review that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the standard form
$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$
you see which letters correspond to which *coefficients*, which isn't the same as the entire terms.

For example, $a$ is the coefficient of $x^2$, not $a=x^2$. Comparing with:
$$x^2+y^2+4x-4y-17=0$$
you get $a=1$, ..., and $f=-17$.

Now notice that there is no term containing $xy$, so the term of the form $bxy$ has which coefficient? That makes $b=\ldots$.

---

**Hint**:

> $$x^2+y^2+\color{blue}{0xy}+4x-4y-17=0$$

Comment: Why is there no term containing $bxy$ in this equation of a cricle? Is there a specific reason for that, should I simply accept it? Will $bxy$ be missing in all equations of a circle, or was I just "unlucky" to get an equation without it?

Comment: I would say _lucky_ instead of _unlucky_ since it makes it easier to convert it to the standard form. With the term, it wouldn't be a circle anymore (but something else such as an ellipse or hyperbola).

Comment: Nice, thank you! I get it now!

Comment: Alright, you're welcome! Note that also _with_ that mixed term in $x$ and $y$ you can convert to some standard form (of an ellipse/hyperbola), but it will be harder to do so.

Comment: **One final question**: Where did you find this form: $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$
What is the name of that?

Comment: Based on the letters used in your question, I assumed/guessed that they were referring to a standard form of this kind - it is common to write the general form in this way.

Comment: Okay, so to clarify, it is just called "The general form of the equation of a circle"? Calling it "the general form" is ambiguous, since it might cause confusing if the context is unknown.

Comment: Terminology can differ from source to source; in any case is "$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$" the _most general form of a cartesian equation of a conic section_ (not necessarily a circle). One can try to rewrite/simplify this to one of the "standard forms" of a specific conic sections (circle, ellipse, hyperbola, parabola).

Comment: @RyanCameron There is no “cross term” in the equation of a circle because of its symmetry: no matter how you rotate it, it looks the same. Compare this to other types of conics, for which an $xy$ term appears when you rotate them away from standard position. It doesn’t work the other way around, though: if there’s no $xy$ term, you have to look at other parts of the equation in order to conclude that it represents a circle.

Answer (score 0):

$b$ is the coefficient of the $xy$ term.  In this case it happens to be $0$.  When $a=c$ and $b=0$, the conic is a circle.

Actually,  it should be $ax^2+bxy+cx^2+dx+ey+f=0$, for the general conic,so that $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are the *coefficients* of the terms.

So we would have $a=1\\b=0\\c=1\\d=4\\e=-4\\f=-17$.